# Error when compiling cannont access class in the subdirectory

Tags: java, import, package

I got an error:

> classpath.java:2: error: cannot access student
>   import path.student;
>              ^
>     bad class file: ./path/student.class
>       class file contains wrong class: Lecture5_exercise.path.student
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

here is folder structure:

[image]

i hava a main "classpath.java" under folder lecture_5_exercise. 
i am trying to access "student.class" in "path" folder which is a sub-directory of lecture_5_exercise.

```
import path.*;
public class classpath {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  student test = student.create();
    }
}
```

edit:
here is my student.java

```
package Lecture5_exercise.path;

class student {

private student(){}

protected void f(){
    System.out.println("protected member! ");
}
public static student create(){
    return new student();
}}
```

Comment: what's inside student.java?  Does it have a package declaration at the top?  like: package path;  Have you been moving these class files around after they were compiled?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime posted inside student.java   I didn't move them around after they were compiled.

Comment: I added an answer based on your update.  Let me know if that import change fixes your error.

Comment: Have you tried using an IDE and following Java conventions like capitalized class names and no underscores in packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for importing in Java is not to use wildcards.  Just type out the full import with the package name and the class name.

```
import Lecture5_exercise.path.student;
```

It's cleaner and you're less likely to run into errors like this.

[Check out Google's Java style guide.](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i got new error: error: package Lecture5_exercise.path does not exist.  I am checking your link right now.

Comment: @stacker well, if your student class says package Lecture5_exercise.path; and your code is throwing an error, then you probably don't have the package in your classpath.  Have you been moving around the .class files manually?  Are you developing this in an IDE?

Comment: I haven't moved any class around, I compiled the student first, then the classpath.java right away. I'm using visual studio code.

Comment: It works right now, thank you u all guys. I changed the student.java: from package Lecture5_exercise.path; to package path;

Comment: but, can anyone tell me why?